# How to restrict all but defined accounts to access folders on MS server?

Tags: permissions, directory, icacls

I've been trying to only allow defined members on Active Directory from accessing folders used for an IIS server.
There are too many accounts to deny one by one leaving only one or two users to access the subdirectory.
I cannot get past the `builtin\users` group. If I remove or deny it, nobody can access the folder any longer.
Tried both ICACLS and GUI for a couple days now with "close but no cigar" results.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot get past the builtin\users group. If I remove or deny it,
>   nobody can access the folder any longer.

Naturally. Remove that and add the users or groups that should have access.

Don't (in most cases) use Deny permissions.

Comment: Seconded. Just prepare a new group, add users, who requires acces and remove all other groups.

Answer (score 0):

Adding users or groups after removing builtin\users did not grant rights.
The biggest challenge to finding the solution was that the response of "successful" was misleading. Had to check again with the GUI Advanced security properties of the folder to verify.

The only way I've gotten this to finally work including files within the folder was to run the following in order:

ICACLS .(dot-slash-foldername-slash)* /T /Q /C /RESET

icacls .(dot-slash-foldername-slash) /inheritance:e

ICACLS .(dot-slash-foldername-slash)* /T /Q /C /RESET

icacls .(dot-slash-foldername) /grant:r (domain-slash-username):R

icacls .(dot-slash-foldername-slash)* /grant:r (domain-slash-username):R

icacls .(dot-slash-foldername) /inheritance:d

icacls .(dot-slash-foldername) /remove "builtin\users"

*Answer does not allow for actual slash, etc. characters, I've put the character names for the next person to follow.

I had 200 stores and 300 users in various combinations of access needs and rights so used a spreadsheet to create scripts to get done.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.